# PHP Multidimensional associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am just wondering if this code I have is a multidimensional associative array. I only ask because after doing research on multidimensional arrays I could't find the difference between the two because they looked the same. Is this code a associative array or just a standard multidim array?

```
$win = array('Name'=> 
                        array('Jane Doe ', 'Nash Patel ', 'Joe Public '), 
             'Date'=>
                        array('7 October 2015 ', '14 October 2014 ', '12 October 2016 '));

foreach($win as $element => $namedate) {
    echo '<strong>' . $element . '</strong><br>';
    foreach($namedate as $both) {
       echo $both . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a multidimensional array.

The first level is associative because the keys are `Name` and `Date`.

The second level subarrays are indexed (not associative).  This means `Jane Doe`'s index is `0`, `Nash Patel` is `1`, and `Joe Public` is `2`.

Although you can if you wish, keys do not need to be written when declaring indexed elements -- PHP will spare you that tedious job.

Examples:

```
$one_dim=['Name'=>'Jane Doe ']; // 1-dimensional associative array with one element

$one_dim=['Jane Doe '];         // 1-dimensional indexed array with one element

$mult_dim=[                     // multi-dimensional associative array with indexed subarrays
    'Name'=>[                   // associative
        0=>'Jane Doe ',         // indexed
        1=>'Nash Patel ',       // indexed
        2=>'Joe Public '        // indexed
    ],
    'Date'=>[                   // associative
        0=>'7 October 2015 ',   // indexed
        1=>'14 October 2014 ',  // indexed
        2=>'12 October 2016 '   // indexed
    ]
];
```

Comment: How am I able to get the whole array to be associative then without making it indexed?

Comment: You can manually declare the keys for each subarray.  When you declare the keys, php will not apply auto-incremented numeric keys for you.  What do you have in mind?  Does it help you to use the `Name` values as keys and `Date` values as values?  Have a look at [this demo link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf3ef55b074e9dc118ffa2d7db832f7c37e3acb4).